# Convert RGBA to just RGB but retain color in C#

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, rgb, rgba

The below color is `rgba(55, 103, 235, 0.53)` on a white background. However is there code in c#/.NET that convert that to the actual rgb without opacity but retain the same color.  The rgba is actually `rgb(149, 174, 244)` when I hover over it with a color picker.

[image]

Comment: And your question is ...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this works on any background color, but for your example, you can calucate the values like this:

```
value = backgroundValue - (backgroundValue - colorValue) * alphaValue
-----
r = 255 - (255 - 55)  * 0.53  = 149
g = 255 - (255 - 103) * 0.53 ~= 174
b = 255 - (255 - 235) * 0.53 ~= 244
```